# App Not Setup: Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing OAuth with Facebook. The application is an Android app and is able to communicate with Facebook.

However when I click the login button:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton android:id = "@+id/btFacebook" android:layout_width = "wrap_content" android:layout_height = "wrap_content" android: layout_gravity = "center_horizontal" android: layout_marginTop = "30dp" />
```

By clicking the first time (after creating the Facebook APP) Login works, ie, can perform the entire flow.

From the second time I click this button, the Facebook displays this sentence:

"App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login general public"

I've tried everything:

1. Altered Roles on Facebook panel;
2. Modified the Status & Review on Facebook panel;
3. Rebooted the Cell;

Nothing seems to solve.

Comment: Have you added the Android Platform in Basic settings. And have you taken the app live?

Comment: Yes, I added the Android Platform, set Package Name, Class Name, Key Hashes (from degub.keystore), and put 'yes' on Single Sign On.

I'm developing the application yet. 

The application show me "Loanding..." from Facebook, before enter on Facebook and show me: 

"App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login general public".

I thought, having in Facebook roles my facebook user (as admin), I would not have put the application as Public.

Comment: When I click on "Login in with Facebook", the Facebook show me: "Invalid Key Hash. The Key hash ... does not match any stored".

When I click for second time on "Login in with Facebook", the Facebook show me:  "App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login general public"

But the Key hashes are configured.